# Execute WinHTTrack command with PHP

Tags: php, command-line, command

I just want to execute command from my localhost. A WinHTTrack tool for website copier installed on my system. When i am using Windows Command Line to execute this command. it is working fine. But with PHP No result...

A code sample here :

```
<?php

echo exec("C:\Program Files\WinHTTrack\httrack 'http://in.yahoo.com/example_page.html' -O 'save_folder/in.yahoo.com/' '+in.yahoo.com/*' -v");    

?>
```

**Updated Question**
Hello

With this code i just want to test httrack command line exec on windows for my future use.

```
$url = 'http://myweb.com/index.html';
$dest = '/tmp/';
echo $command = 'C:\Program Files\WinHTTrack\httrack ' .$url. ' -O ' .$dest. ' +myweb.com/* -v';        
echo exec($command, $output,$error); 
print_r($output);
print_r($error);
```

**Output: Array()**

**Error : 1**

failed. no result :(

But when i am running manually form windows command line

```
C:\Program Files\WinHTTrack\httrack http://myweb.com/index.html -O /tmp/ +myweb.com/* -v
```

Giving me a accurate result. any solution please.

Answer (score 0):

see in php.ini if this function enabled

```
disable_functions =exec
```

and omit here

also see the output like:

```
 exec("my command", $output);
 print_r($output);
```

Comment: My php ini showing " disable_functions =    " means no any function is disable

Answer (score 0):

Path to WinHTTrack contains space. You need to escape this path (and arguments too) but not with ', instead use escapeshellarg().

Comment: You can't successfully execute this command even in command-line because path contains space. Try this:

exec('"C:\Program Files\WinHTTrack\httrack" "http://in.yahoo.com/example_page.html" -O "save_folder/in.yahoo.com/" "+in.yahoo.com/*" -v');

Comment: not solving problem with your ans, and now i am going to put out my hairs.. :(

Comment: Would you mind sharing output / error message which you get when executing this command in Windows command-line?